Meixner and the Impossibility of Non-equilibirum Entropy
Meixner in a series of publications, see a short list below, starting from 1959 criticized and ultimately denied the possibility of defining the entropy concept in an irreversible process. His criticism is based on an almost trivial observation well-known in lumped circuit network theory familiar to every EE undergraduate: the positive real impedance function between any two nodes of a linear network of $RLC$ elements satisfying Kirchhoff's law while it can always be synthesized by a properly selected set of resistors, inductors and capacitors, that synthesis is not unique. In fact, there is an infinity of such equivalent realizations having the same impedance but completely different topologies and component values.
Because of this non-uniqueness the externally accessible and measurable quantities, namely the driving point voltage and current does not determine the structure of the network.
The simplest example of such non-uniqueness is shown below[4]: a resistor $R$ on the left is equivalent to either of the two $RLC$ circuits to its right. Of course, this can be iterated ad infinitum, and there are many other non-iterated versions, too.

In [5] Meixner writes:

It is shown that to an isothermal electrical
network one can apply thermodynamic reasoning. When it is considered as a black box, that is, characterised by its impedance only, one can assign to the same state an infinite number of different entropy values. Thus one is led to doubt the existence of a unique nonequilibrium entropy in continuous matter, if one adopts here again the black box point of view, that is, if constitutive equations are used which relate the external variables only. Network models which also model the temperature by a voltage at one pair of
terminals confirm the conjecture.

In [7] he writes:

Electrical networks with the same voltage-current
relation are not equivalent with respect to their energy
dissipations. This is quite obvious in the example of the
voltage-current relation $u(t) = Ri(t)$. Therefore we should
also expect that the thermodynamic constitutive equations
of a material on the lowest level of description do not determine a unique entropy production. This would imply
that we cannot assign a unique entropy to a material state
on the lowest level of description.

So far so good but then in [4] he illustrates this non-uniqueness of the entropy using the reasoning as follows (Google Translation):

We will illustrate the relationships further by means of a special switching-on process. Let $u(t) = 0$ for $t < 0$ and $u(t) = u_0$ for $t > 0$. For the network in Figure 1b, this gives the Joule heat output $N(t)$, as shown by the curve in Figure 2. This means $τ = RC$. The horizontal line with the ordinate 1 gives the Joule heat output $u^2_0/R$ of the simple resistor for the same supply. The hatched area between the curve and the horizontal line gives the deficit of Joule heat in the network in Figure 1b compared to the pure resistor in Figure 1a. This deficit is found in the
network in Figure 1b at time $t = \infty$ as stored energy in the capacitor and in the coil. It is equal to $Cu^2_0$
and is found in equal parts in the coil and capacitor. It
is particularly important to emphasize that this stored energy is just as lost as the energy converted into Joule heat if one takes the "black box" standpoint, i.e. if one
only allows manipulation of the voltage at the pair of terminals as an operation. This is because the "black box" then behaves the same for each of the network implementations in Figure 1, i.e. like the resistor R in Figure 1a, in which the power put into it is always immediately dissipated and none of it can be recovered
as electrical work.
The situation changes, of course, if we allow further operations and thus gain additional information about the properties of the network contained in the "black box". One such possibility would be to bring out a second pair of terminals, which terminals, it is certainly possible to recover some of the electrical energy fed into the network. But even if you bring out two or three or more pairs of terminals to which you can apply any voltage curves and measure the currents, you can perhaps rule out that the network that behaves like an ohmic resistor is actually an ohmic resistor or one of the other types in Figure 1. But even then there are still an infinite number of "black boxes" with the same behavior at the increased pairs of terminals, and it is generally not possible to fully recover stored energy as electrical energy or to determine the energy dissipated in the ohmic resistors.


I believe and this is what I wish to discuss, that while the calculation is correct, the conclusion is wrong. In fact, all the stored energy is dissipated if we disconnect the voltage supple $u_0$ at some finite time $t = t_1 < ∞$ after which during the network discharge transient all the stored energies in the capacitor and inductor will dissipate in the resistors. So it is not the network impedance but the unphysical assumption of having constant bias supplying an infinite amount of energy all the way through $t → ∞$ that conceals the stored energy.
In other words, we do not need other terminals to observe the innards of the network as long as we apply physically more realistic, proper terminal drive.
Furthermore, supplying and dissipating an infinite amount of thermal energy into a thermal reservoir of fixed temperature itself is violating the fundamental rule of only "negligible" entropy change affecting the reservoir. In other words, we are only allowed to exchange an amount of entropy with the reservoir that relative to its static entropy content will keep the process reversible within the reservoir , ie., at a constant temperature. Exchanging an infinite amount of entropy cannot be insignificant relative to whatever it already contains no matter how slowly we do it.
Am I right? I would appreciate any comments that you may have on this.

Meixner: "Impedanz und Lagrange-Funktion linearer dissipativer
Systeme," Zeitschrift fur Physik 156, 200-210 (1959)
Meixner:"Thermodynamics of Electrical Networks and the
Onsager-Casimir Reciprocal Relations," JOURNAL OF MATHEMATICAL PHYSICS VOLUME 4,
NUMBER 2 FEBRUARY 1963
Meixner:"Network Theory and Its Relation to the
Theory of Linear Systems," IRE TRANSACTIONS ON ANTENNAS AND
PROPAGATION December, 1959
Meixner:"Beziehungen zwischen Netzwerktheorie
und Thermodynamik," Springer Fachmedien Wiesbaden GmbH, 1967
Domingos, Nina, Whitelaw, ed.,: Foundations of Continuum
Thermodynamics, MacMillan 1974, pp129-142
Stuart, Gal-Or, Brainard: A Critical Review of Thermodynamics, University of Pittsburg, Mono Book, 1979, pp37-48,
Meixner: "The entropy problem in thermodynamics of processes," Rheol. Acta 12, 465-467 (1973)


@Quillo you know Meixner, and you know he tried to bridge the chasm between "Onsager-Prigogine" and "Eckart-Truesdell". What do you think, do I misunderstand him?
